# Why does sql select statement fail when I define Monday as the first day of the week?

Tags: php, mysql

I have an sql select statement that returns all rows who's "last_edited" variable (timestamp)
is within the current week:

```
SELECT vote FROM votes WHERE WEEK(vote_time)=WEEK(now())
```

This works very well, but I want the week to start on Monday and not Sunday, so I tried this:

```
SELECT vote FROM votes WHERE WEEK(vote_time, 1)=WEEK(now(), 1)
```

but this is not returning any results. Any idea why?

Comment: And you are sure there are results? Although it wouldnt realy matter running this on friday. But perhaps you can try `SELECT WEEK(vote_time) as w1, WEEK(vote_time,1) as w2 FROM votes` to see what its returning

Comment: This `WEEK(vote_time)=WEEK(now())` equal to this `WEEK(vote_time, 1)=WEEK(now(), 1)` you are confused what you need :)

Comment: What I was wanting is that the week comparison runs from Monday to Sunday not from Sunday to Saturday, as this is important elsewhere in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
WEEK(timestamp, 1)
```

Check out the [docs.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week)

Comment: how would this change anything? op's obviously got timestamps, or the first sample query wouldn't be working. datetime values are dates as far as the week() function is concerned.